# PAYG sim and TOR

Tags: orbot, android

I would like to use Tor/Orfox/Orbot on Android while using a Pay-As-You-Go SIM card. I live in the United Kingdom.

Is this possible?

If so, did you encounter any issues?

Do I need a registered SIM?

Thanks.

Comment: for Tor itself it is completely samey how you connect to the internet... for your anonymity it is perhaps not!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible:

1. Download and start Orbot
2. Click on VPN Disable/Tor-Enabled Apps
3. Choose the Game

It is now on Tor. However, you should know what Tor is. It is a way of keeping you anonymous by hiding your IP address.

This will have 2 effects.

1. Your account may be autobanned for doing it so as to protect the other players from anonymous cheaters.
2. It will be slow as crap because Tor [encrypts and sends your information all over the world](https://2019.www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en) before it gets to the game and back.